# How to Render React router-dom Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on ReactJS project, Now I have render routes based on API response if the API returns user type User then I have to render user routes. Otherwise I have to render Admin routes and a 404 page.

```js
function Index() {
    const userType = "user" // fetching this data from Api

    if (userType === "user")
        return (
          <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact>
                  <User/>
              </Route>
          </Switch>
        )
    else
        return (
          <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact>
                  <Admin/>
              </Route>
          </Switch>
        )
}
```

Comment: What version of react-router did you install ?